# multiple for loop in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In django the syntax for using a for loop over a list or array is:

```
{% for each in list %}
    <td>{{ each }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

if i use nested loop then the data span over multiple columns.

How to iterate over two or more lists at same time. I have 5 lists i want to iterate over.

e.g in python i can use something like:

```
for x,y in zip(ls1, ls2):
    #Do your work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `foo = zip(list1,list2,list3,...)` inside your view, then iterate in template:

```
{% for a,b,c,d,e in list %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

Another option is to write your custom {% for %} template tag.

Btw: Using `list` as variable is not good practice because you override `list()` function

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the two lists before render the template, and pass the zip as parameter:

```
zippedList = zip(list1, list2)
return render('template.html', {'list': zippedList})
```

And in the template:

```
{% for item1, item2 in list %}
```

This way you can iterate over the two lists.